# Angular Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded -migration

Tags: angular, frontend, migration

I have faced the same issue, and I still haven't resolved it. If anyone has a solution, please provide an answer.

./src/main.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dijfn.png)

Comment: do you want to migrate to angular 17?

Comment: yes I migrate  to angular v17.

Comment: default project in angular 17 use vite instead of webpack. Follow this instruction
https://angular.io/guide/esbuild

Comment: „ same issue“ than what?

Comment: i would at least upload your package.json file, to see what you have in it. have you tried removing package-lock.json file if you have one, removing `node_modules` folder or cleaning cache?